# Parsing xml (xforms) document with javascript `document.getElementsByTagName` not working in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, xml, cordova

I am having some trouble parsing xform xml with javascript.

The structure of the root of the xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ex="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa">
  <h:head>
    <h:title>Phonegap Survey</h:title>        
  </h:head>
  <h:body>A ton more tags here</h:body>
</h:html>
```

I am using firefox (v.12) to develop and trying to deploy to phonegap/cordova on android.  I am getting the data from an odk server using jquery ajax.  I am specifiying `dataType: 'xml'` and it is responding with a document object as expected.  In firefox I have written an app that presents data from this xml to the user.  I am using built in javascript DOM functions like:

```
var title = surveyXML.getElementsByTagName('h:title')[0].firstChild.data
var body = surveyXML.getElementsByTagName('h:body')[0];
var text = surveyXML.getElementsByTagName('text')
```

I have written the full app (and it works fine) using these methods.  But now that I have copied my files over to phonegap (running cordovo 1.7.0, on android emulator 2.3) on eclipse none of the DOM calls are returning elements!! I get something like:

```
05-31 13:21:28.686: D/CordovaLog(841): file:///android_asset/www/formcontroller.js:
line 159 : TypeError: Result of expression 'body' [undefined] is not an object.
```

For all the calls. I have verified that the device has the correct xml (it's not empty or anything)

So having to get this done I tried to use jQuery to navigate the document object hoping it knew something I didn't.  Using calls like:

```
$(surveyXML).find('title');
$(surveyXML).find('h:title')
```

do not work at all.  But tags without the `h:` prefix work fine,  if I were to search for `$(surveyXML).find('text')` it returns all `text` elements as expected.

Seeing as the root elements are `<html>`  I tried to specify `dataType: html` (just to try it even though the document is clearly marked as `<?xml version="1.0"?>`)  and jquery is unable to parse it, as expected.

So I am wondering: **How can I parse this XML cross platform so that it can work both in a browser and phonegap.  And, supposing that it can't work in both using the same DOM manipulation functions, how can I at least make it work in phonegap??**

As always any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

**EDIT: For right Now I am just manually referencing the exact locations of the elements like to get to body I am going `xml.firstChild.children[1]`.  Because I am underdeadline.  I def feel like there should be a way to use getElementsByTagName still. ty.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been unanswered for 2 weeks so I am just posting what I did.

For right Now I am just manually referencing the exact locations of the elements like to get to body I am going xml.firstChild.children[1].

So all I did was not search for tags with the namespace and just reference them directly.